# RxJava Single filtering a list inside an object and return its object with the filtered list

Tags: android, filter, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

i'm using RxJava2 (Single) with retrofit for network requests, when receiving the response, amog other fields that the object contains, theres a list of objects, what im trying achieve is to filter out the objects(in the list) that contains a particular 'id'
and I want it to happen on the background thread of course, and then emit response after the object has its list filtered.

***out of scope***
is there a way I can detect in each operator which thread its using ?

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1")
```

API

```
data class Result(val id: Int)

data class MyObject(val values: List<Result> = emptyList())

interface RetroFitApi {
    fun getAll(): Single<MyObject>
}

internal class RetroFitApiImpl : RetroFitApi {
    override fun getAll(): Single<MyObject> {
        return Single.fromCallable {
            MyObject(
                listOf(Result(1), Result(2), Result(3))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Retrofit usage, when Retrofit has no own threading model (androidTest)

```
import android.os.Looper
import io.reactivex.Single
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.Test
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit 

@Test
internal fun name() {
    val api = RetroFitApiImpl()

    val test = api.getAll()
        // make sure the subscribe lambda is called in background-thread
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { result ->
            // remove all elements, which are id == 1
            result.copy(values = result.values.filterNot { it.id == 1 })
        }
        // move emit, which will probably be emitted from Schedules#io-Thread to Main-Loop. Therefore after applying observeOn the onNext emit in subscribe will be emitted on the UI-Android-Loop
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .test()

    test.awaitDone(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    assertThat(test.lastThread()).isEqualTo(Looper.getMainLooper().thread)

    assertThat(test.values()).containsExactly(
        MyObject(values = listOf(Result(2), Result(3)))
    )
}
```

Regarding

> out of scope is there a way I can detect in each operator which thread its using ?

You can only test for it with a TestConsumer (Single#test), wihch Thread was last called. You can not know on which Thread an onNext will be emitted during runtime, because RxJava does not care about threading at all, only if you take it into your own hands with observeOn/ subscribeOn. By default onNext will be called on the calling-thread. If the calling thread, is als the subscribing one, your result will (probably) be emitted synchronous, if no threading is involved.

Further reading:

> http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html

Comment: Hey thanks, buts its not answering my question, first of all im using RxJava 2, and as mentioned, im receiving an Object that contains a list, and I want to iterate on this list and remove items from that contains some id with a specific value, and that I want to return to 'onSuccess' the object itself (with the filtered array inside of it)

Comment: @RavidRinek, thank you for your feedback. Maybe next time provide some example code, that I do not have to guess, how your Objects are build up. Furthermore it does not matter whether you use RxJava2 or RxJava3. The API is mostly the same, only the imports changed. I will try to update my answer acording to your specification.